# Remove empty array in Resource::Collection not working Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to remove empty array when its return. I have been trying in many different ways, help plz
My controller looks :

```
public function index()
{
    return JobsResource::collection(Jobs::all())->filter();
}
```

my resource file look:

```
class JobsCollection extends Resource
```

{

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $applicants_count =Job_applicants::where('job_id',$this->id)->get()->count();

    if ($applicants_count>0) {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'deadline' => $this->deadline,
            'applicants_count' => $applicants_count,
            'applicants' => new EmployeesResource($this->Employeess->take(2))
        ];
    }
}
```

}

it always return an empty array 
output :

```
[
 [],
```

{
      "id":99,
      "title":"Construction Administrator - The Woodlands",
      "deadline":"2018-06-30",
      "applicants_count":10,
      "applicants":[
         {
            "name":"Mr. Job Seeker",
            "pivot":{
               "job_id":99,
               "employee_id":1
            }
         },
         {
            "name":"Michale Feil",
            "pivot":{
               "job_id":99,
               "employee_id":2
            }
         }
      ]
   }

Comment: it is maybe occurs becouse `toArray($request)` function outside of `if` you does not return anythig

Comment: thats why its return null, if i used else condition then its also null... any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
public function index() {
    $jobs = Jobs::has('Employeess')->with('Employeess')->withCount('Employeess')->get();

    return JobsResource::collection($jobs);
}
```

Resource file:

```
class JobsCollection extends Resource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {
            return [
                'id' => $this->id,
                'title' => $this->title,
                'deadline' => $this->deadline,
                'applicants_count' => $this->Employeess_count,
                'applicants' => new EmployeesResource($this->Employeess->take(2))
            ];
    }
}
```

Comment: its working... if i want to use any condition like if count 3...then how could i do,, im just learning, i am not a developer... can you hint me plz...

Comment: @Shofin You should mark this answer as solution and create a new question. BTW you can read about withCount() by [clicking here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) .

Comment: You're Welcome @Shofin